# DataTables Slyling in a Shiny App by including the jQuery UI integration for DataTables

Tags: jquery, r, datatable, shiny, dt

I would like to slyle DataTables in a Shiny App by including the jQuery UI. I have integrated tags in the header but the style was not taken into account.

Example code:

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(
ui= pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel(list('Examples of DataTables',
          singleton(tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type ="text/css", href = "https://cdn.datatables.net/v/ju-1.11.4/dt-1.10.13/datatables.min.css"))),
          singleton(tags$head(tags$script(type='text/javascript',src='https://cdn.datatables.net/v/ju-1.11.4/dt-1.10.13/datatables.min.js'))))),
sidebarPanel(
checkboxGroupInput('show_vars', 
                   'Columns in diamonds to show:', 
                   names(diamonds),
                   selected = names(diamonds))
),
mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel('diamonds',
           dataTableOutput("mytable1")),
  tabPanel('mtcars',
           dataTableOutput("mytable2")),
  tabPanel('iris',
           dataTableOutput("mytable3"))
  ))),

 server = function(input, output) {

  output$mytable1 = renderDataTable({
   library(ggplot2)
   diamonds[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]
  })

  output$mytable2 = renderDataTable({mtcars}, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE))

  output$mytable3 = renderDataTable({
  iris}, options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 30, 50), pageLength = 5))
  }))
```

I would like to display the data table as shown in the example below taken from

https://datatables.net/manual/styling/jqueryui[image: ][1]]

Answer (score 0):

This works like this, when I open the table in the browser, and this doesn't work in the RStudio viewer. That should work in Shiny, but all the functionalities provided by the DT javascript are lost.

```
dtable <- datatable(iris)
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "judtcss", "1.11.4",
  c(href =  "https://cdn.datatables.net/v/ju-1.11.4/dt-1.10.13/"), 
  stylesheet = "datatables.min.css")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "judt", "1.11.4",
  c(href =  "https://cdn.datatables.net/v/ju-1.11.4/dt-1.10.13/"), 
  script = "datatables.min.js")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
dtable$dependencies[[1]] <- NULL

dtable
```

[image]